# An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

Anybody can help me with this code I am getting this error message:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The existing object is in the    Modified state. An object can only be added to the ObjectStateManager again if it is in the added state.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review  the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: An object with the same key already exists in the    ObjectStateManager. The existing object is in the Modified state. An object can only be added to the    ObjectStateManager again if it is in the added state.

Source Error:

```
Line 90:    public void AddToTwitter(Twitter twitter)
Line 91:    {
Line 92:        base.AddObject("Twitter", twitter);
Line 93:    }
```

Source File: C:\Users\dell\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MvcApplication3\MvcApplication3\Models\TwitterEntity.Designer.cs    Line: 92

the code is :

```
Models.TwitterEntities entity = new Models.TwitterEntities();
Models.Twitter tw = new Models.Twitter();

foreach (Hashtable item in (ArrayList)hs["results"])
{                
    foreach (DictionaryEntry subitem in item)
    {
        if (subitem.Key.ToString() == "from_user")
        {
            tw.from_user = (string)subitem.Value;
            Response.Write("<br>" + (string)subitem.Value);
            entity.AddToTwitter(tw);
        }
        if (subitem.Key.ToString() == "to_user")
        {
            tw.to_user = (string)subitem.Value;
            Response.Write("<br>" + (string)subitem.Value);
            entity.AddToTwitter(tw);
        }
        entity.SaveChanges();              
    }   
}
```

Comment: You should use generic collections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to add the same `Twitter` instance every time you go through the loop.

You need to create a new instance in each iteration (inside the loop body).

Answer (score 0):

@Slaks wouldn't he need to free each of the instances as well will he run into a stackoverflow error forgive the pun..LOL

```
Models.Twitter tw = new Models.Twitter(); 
// do code...
```

// tw.Dispose() or tw = null if it does not implement IDisposable